# Tab Order VSCode 2022

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs

I have a collection of tabs open. I would like <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd> to cycle through them from left to right, and <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Tab</kbd> right to left.

I can use <kbd>Ctrl+PgUp/Down</kbd> for this. However, I'd rather just use <kbd>Ctrl+(Shift)+Tab</kbd>, as this is what I'm used to.

I've been trawling through forums, SO posts, Reddit posts, etc, but cannot see how to do this in the current VSCode. I've been looking for this simple option for about 30mins, trying many suggestions which are outdated. I am admitting defeat and asking for an up-to-date solution here!

Comment: define a keybinding for the `Tab` variants with the commands bound to the `PageUpDown` variants

Comment: @rioV8 This is something I thought of. How do I do this?

Comment: there is a fine page documenting keybindings in VSC and there are plenty of examples of that here at SO, or on many README pages of extensions (some of them are written by me)

Comment: @rioV8 if you can link me up, that would be grand, thanks! :)